# How to workaround exclude_matches bug without programmatic injection by rewriting include_matches?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, expression, content-script

I'm building a Chrome Extension and I'm having issues because of the [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100106) in Chrome which causes `exclude_matches` to fail with CSS. I know there are ways to bypass it using Programmatic Injection, but this is causing some issues with performance so I'm wondering if someone can think of some way to rewrite my `include_matches` in such a way that doesn't include the things I want to exclude (as anything which isn't matched is automatically excluded). It's a long shot, but I figured if anyone can do it they'll be on here! An example to work from will be the following code:

```
{
....
  "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [ "http://example.com/*" , "http://*.example.com/*" ]
  }]
....
}
```

Obviously the above covers any links on `example.com`, but I'd like to know if there's a way to rewrite it in such a way that the URL `example.com/z/` doesn't fit the rules, but a URL such as `example.com/z/s/` could still work.

Basically the only URL which isn't allowed is one in the above format ("`/z/`"), so I wondered if there's a way to specify to not allow URLs with a slash in that position. As daft as it sounds, I think I thought through the regular expressions too much, so any help is appreciated!

Even as I type this I feel I could be stuck with PI, but worth a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google's ["Match patterns and globs"](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs) don't always operate like one might expect.  Especially, with the `?` wildcard.  You'd think you could use `http://example.com/?*` as [it's supposed to match "any single character" (and not an empty string)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs).

Anyway, it's a bit of a hack but you could use *at least* 26 `include_globs` rules, like so:

```
{
    ....
    "content_scripts":  [ {
        "matches":      [   "http://example.com/*",
                            "http://*.example.com/*"
        ],
        "include_globs":[   "*example.com/z/a*",
                            "*example.com/z/b*",
                            "*example.com/z/c*",
                            "*example.com/z/d*",
        // Etc., etc.
                            "*example.com/z/x*",
                            "*example.com/z/y*",
                            "*example.com/z/z*"
        ]
    } ]
    ....
}
```

Alas, the rules are case-sensitive, so depending on the sites/servers, you may need to duplicate the rules for uppercase and for international characters.